# Facebook (Multi-Friend) Request Dialogue: Track amount of users invited?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a Facebook-integrated online game and want to do the following in PHP:

I want users to be able to 'unlock' certain features depending on the amount of friends they invited using the Multi-Friend Request API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

Basically I'm looking to make code similar to this working:

```
if($user['friendsInvited'] => 5){
echo "You invited 5 or more friends"
} else {
echo "<button onclick='showInviteDialogue()'>Invite Friends</button>"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close... you've just got the = and > backwards... try this

```
if($user['friendsInvited'] >= 5)
```

Easiest way to remember the order, is that it reads as "greater than or equal to"

As for getting the actual number, when the sharing is done by the user, facebook will hit your page with a "to" param in the query string that contains an array of user id's, you could do a count on this (or add the count to how many they previously shared to).

Check out the 'return data' section on the page you linked to

Comment: Thank you, the answer was practically under my nose!